# $\dim H^0(\mathcal{O}_Z \otimes K_X)^* = \dim H^0(\mathcal{O}_Z)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular quasiprojective variety and $Z$ a closed subvariety of length $n$ i.e. $\dim H^0(Z, \mathcal{O}_Z) = n$. I found an identity in FGA Explained claiming that $\dim H^0(\mathcal{O}_Z \otimes K_X)^* = \dim H^0(\mathcal{O}_Z) = n$, where $K_X$ is the canonical bundle, but I can't see why that would be.

Comment: Length $n$, as in $Z$ is finite? Then $H^0$ of any line bundle restricted to $Z$ is just an $n$-dimensional vector space.